# AJAX jquery form page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

When you press the button on the form page is reloaded.

```
$(document).on('click', '.share_file_form', function(event) {
    $(event.target).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://api.server.com/share/",
                timeout: 20000,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() {
                },
                success: function(msg){
                },
                error: function(msg){
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

What is wrong?
What is wrong?
What is wrong?

Comment: You propably forgot to stop the submit event of your form

Answer (score 0):

Add a `event.preventDefault();` at the end of the function. This prevents the default event (i.e. form submission) from getting triggered upon the completion of your function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.share_file_form', function(event) {
    $(event.target).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://api.server.com/share/",
                timeout: 20000,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() {
                },
                success: function(msg){
                },
                error: function(msg){
                }
            });
        }
    });    

     event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: If the OP is going to do it this way, they should use event.preventDefault(); instead of return false. Also, it seems odd to add validation after a click event (instead of on document ready).

Answer (score 0):

The validation plugin doesn't really work that way. Your code looks a little tricky to reason about, because you're attaching validation to a click event. What happens if you implement it like this instead:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    function submitHandler (form) {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://api.server.com/share/",
           timeout: 20000,
           data: $(form).serialize(),
           beforeSend: function() {},
           success: function(msg) {},
           error: function(msg) {}
       });
    }
    $(function () {
        $('.share_file_form').validate({
            submitHandler: submitHandler
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"What is wrong? What is wrong? What is wrong?"*

Your code, your code, your code is constructed improperly.

```
$(document).on('click', '.share_file_form', function(event) {
    $(event.target).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({...});
        }
    });    
});
```

**Quote OP:**

> *"When you press the button on the form page is reloaded."*

Yes, that's because the Validation plugin is not yet initialized when you click the button.

**`.validate()` is not the *testing* method; it is the *initialization* method of the plugin.**  It's only called *once*, typically on DOM ready, to initialize the plugin on the form.

You would never need to enclose it within a `click` event handler since every relevant mouse event is already *automatically* captured by the plugin.

You are also not allowed to attach `.validate()` to anything other than the `<form>` object.

This is the working version of your code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {         // <-- DOM Ready event

    $('.share_file_form').validate({   // <-- initialize plugin on form
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({...});
            return false;              // <-- block regular submit when using ajax
        }
    });    

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ck3sX/**